# Format HTML font and colors in python

Tags: python

I have a function that I wrote that creates a web page in confluence that lists all the AWS Ec2 instances in our accounts. It looks good.

Except that the background is all grey and the font is bold everywhere.

This is my function:

```
def convert_csv_to_html_table(output_file, today):
    output_dir = "../output_files/aws_instance_list/html/"
    htmlfile = output_dir + 'aws-master-list-' + today +'.html'
    count = 0
    html = ''
    with open(output_file,'r') as CSVFILE:
        reader = csv.reader(CSVFILE)
        html += "<table><tbody>"
        for row in reader:
            html += "<tr>"
            # Process the headers
            if count == 0:
                for column in row:
                    html += "<th>%s</th>" % column
                html += "</tr>"
            else:
                # Process the data
                for column in row:
                    html += "<td>%s</td>" % column
                html += "</tr>"
                count += 1
        html += "</tbody></table>"
    with open(htmlfile,'w+') as HTMLFILE:
        HTMLFILE.write(html)
    return htmlfile
```

How can I get the result that only the header has a grey background? And the rest of the page has a white background? Also how do I specify a font and font size in the above code?

Comment: This seems like more of an HTML/CSS question than anything to do with python..

Comment: Or even a Confluence question.

Comment: As both have said above it seems like this question may need to be asked elsewhere. But to add, you may need to determine if you want inline CSS or external CSS. There are many reasons why to choose each, but I would suggest using a separate CSS file. It makes things much easier. Best of luck getting your answer!

Comment: OK thanks guys! I still have to get familiar with CSS. I will work on that. Thanks again!

Comment: If you get to repost the question feel free to tag me. It should be a quick fix.